# Styled Mode : Color theme for bar

Tags: highcharts

Because of the CSP, I need to use Styled mode on highcharts and I need a specific color theme.

I try css but after 10 bar/piece of pie chart, class restart to 0

```
  highcharts-point highcharts-color-9  ->  highcharts-point highcharts- 
  color-0
```

Before styled mode, I have this array of color:

```
    $ob->colors = array("#0017ff","#00a2ff","#7400ff","#ff4500","#ffd100","#00c33d","#f93078","#0bdcc4","#d26bfa","#feaa10","#00ff45","#d1ff00","#96a7d6",
            "#454d1e","#637d6f","#30b2d7","#28e743","#ebab1b","#a6219b","#1da4b9","#3d1fb0","#947a46",
            "#73bceb","#b21cc0","#f8e809","#436e39","#a90650","#3c68b5","#7f76a5","#d68f03","#c9f7cd","#4de457","#9a303b","#401156","#124c38","#f0fa84",
            "#493b8a","#7ef2f9","#a10ce9","#a3b931","#763f1c","#c97539","#9a8b58","#9e503e","#144d87","#5f3a1d","#15331b","#b91eee","#c6bf2f","#3e165c",
            "#a864e7","#f784d4","#21887e",'#228B22','#556B2F','#6B8E23','#808000','#BDB76B','#B8860B','#FFA500','#D2691E','#8B4513','#4682B4','#8B0000',
            '#008B8B','#5F9EA0','#4169E1','#8D38C9','#9E7BFF','#153E7E','#7D053F','#E4317F','#FF00FF','#7E587E','#E0FFFF','#228B22','#556B2F','#6B8E23',
            '#808000','#BDB76B','#B8860B','#FFA500','#D2691E','#8B4513','#4682B4','#8B0000','#008B8B','#5F9EA0','#4169E1','#8D38C9','#9E7BFF','#153E7E',
            '#7D053F','#E4317F','#FF00FF','#7E587E','#E0FFFF');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yn2Lcbrm/
Look here, after, Mellon bar class is highcharts-point highcharts-color-0. Can I do something in css or extend limit of 9 to an another limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the `colorCount` property:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    colorCount: 20
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fjk9qub2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.colorCount